# Keep text centered in button when background color changes

Tags: c#, button, text, center

I am working on some code in c#, when a button appears on the gui the background is green and the text is middle center.  When the user presses the button I change the background color to orange and for some reason the text in the button changes from middle center to top center.  Has anyone encountered this, and if so what is the solution to keep the text middle center?

Here is my code, the text goes into top center.  I want it to stay middle center

```
                buttonAssembly.Text = "Stop";
                buttonAssembly.BackColor = Color.Orange;
```

Here is the code for when the text goes into middle center

```
                buttonAssembly.Text = "Assembly";
                buttonAssembly.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
```

Comment: Sounds like you have code else where causing your issue.

Comment: Not much to go on.  But I have seen text in buttons move when the button is too narrow for the text.  Try widening your button.

Comment: Not sure if its possible, you might have to extend the `Button` class, but you could watch for an event when the `TextAlignment` property changes and just have it always set to `Center`. // What happens when you don't change the text, does the current text move?

Comment: @Les, thanks.  I originally had the text as Stop Assembly.  When I changed it to stop that fixed my problem. Post it as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try widening the button.  If the text gets larger, I've seen its layout change.  I.e. the button is too narrow for the new text width, so it wants to wrap.